# Does react have the notion of an "app" or is it solely components? How to make something global?

Tags: reactjs

I'm interested in creating a mixin/decorator, but I don't want to declare it under every single component that uses it, but still have it available everywhere within the application.

Is that something that exists in react? Can I create tags that become automatically available within the context of the entire app?

How do analytics/i18n libraries work in react? Do you have to import them in every single file where you need translations or tracking?

Fresh beginner here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use globals in React--just like with any other framework--but that's not really the 'React Way' of doing things. Relatedly, the equivalent of an 'app' in React would just be the top-level, root component.

Instead of relying on globals, one should instead either (1) `import` / `require` modules you need in one's component file; or, (2) pass needed functions and values from a parent to child component.

To implement the first method, one would need a bundler like Webpack or Browserify. So, for instance, if one wanted to use a i18n Gettext module like `Jed`, one would instantiate it and export it in one file and then `import` or `require` it in any component file that needs it.

As for the second method, one would pass down props from parent to child or use `context`. While props need to be manually passed down, `context` is always passed down to the entire subtree.

In the previous example, you could put `Jed` functions in a `context`, but the React team does warn: "If you have to use context, use it sparingly," and again, "Just as global variables are best avoided when writing clear code, you should avoid using context in most cases."